# Why can't I write() multiple times on an open file?

Tags: python

I am trying to delete some words from the open file with for loop.
Each loop I open the file and remove the line from the file and rewrite the content to the file.
Finally, I want to generate the contents with the original file.

The problem is after for loop, the file is not overwrote.
It only remove one of words from the dictionary. It seems like when I open the file each iteration of loop, the content of file is not being updated for each loop.
Please advise how to handle the file open/close in this condition.

My code:

```
# I want to delete the line which contains the pair from the dictionary.
# For example, if a line contains "can_option" and "17", then I will delete the line.

dictionary = {"can_optin" : "17", "appPrevAddrStreet": "33"}
fname = "test.txt"
infile = open(fname, 'r')
data = infile.readlines()
infile.close()

def readline(keyword, data, infile):
    for line in data:
        lineNumber = line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
        # line contains "can_option" or "appPreAddrStreet", 
        # then does not write the line to the file.
        if keyword[0] in line and lineNumber == keyword[1]:
            print "Removed: %s" % line
        else:
            infile.write(line)

# start to delete line from here.
for key in dictionary.keys():
    infile= open(fname, 'w')
    # write the contents to the same file again and again until 
    # the loop ends.
    keyword = [key, dictionary[key]]
    # the keyword list will contain ["con_option", "17"]
    readline(keyword, data, infile)
    infile.close()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `infile` is (re)opened with `w` (create and write file) access, but only `readline()` is used on it.  That won't write anything nor will it read anything because the file is always at eof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not reading from the file. You are reading all lines and saving in the `data` variable and then only reading it from `data`, not the written file -

```
dictionary = {"can_optin" : "17", "appPrevAddrStreet": "33"}
fname = "test.txt"
infile = open(fname, 'r')
data = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
```

To read the current lines you have to read after writing the file -

```
dictionary = {"can_optin" : "17", "appPrevAddrStreet": "33"}
fname = "test.txt"

def readline(keyword, data, infile):
    for line in data:
        lineNumber = line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
        # line contains "can_option" or "appPreAddrStreet", 
        # then does not write the line to the file.
        if keyword[0] in line and lineNumber == keyword[1]:
            print "Removed: %s" % line
        else:
            infile.write(line)

# start to delete line from here.
for key in dictionary.keys():
    infile= open(fname, 'r+') # open in read/write mode
    data = infile.readlines() # read again and get updated data
    [...]
    keyword = [key, dictionary[key]]
    [...]
    readline(keyword, data, infile)
    infile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> the content of file is not being updated for each loop

Because you only read data once, at the top of the file

```
data = infile.readlines()
```

If you want each loop to read the most recent copy of the file, you need to read from the file inside the loop.